# Tearable Cloth simulation works on Codepen but not locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to include this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dissimulate/pen/KrAwx#0) into a basic website for school.

The issue is that the code with a few tweaks, will not load locally. I have even put my entire website into [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Clubwho/pen/bVzOJV) as a test and it worked.

It should just be the cloth simulation and nothing else.

Here is the HTML and CSS in its smallest form.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background: #2F4F4F;
}
#c {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Website/JavaScript/ClothSimulation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <div id="top">
        <a id="close"></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The JS is very big as it is a cloth simulation.

```
document.getElementById('close').onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
  return false;
};

// settings

var physics_accuracy = 3,
  mouse_influence = 20,
  mouse_cut = 5,
  gravity = 1200,
  cloth_height = 30,
  cloth_width = 50,
  start_y = 20,
  spacing = 7,
  tear_distance = 60;

window.requestAnimFrame =
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };

var canvas,
  ctx,
  cloth,
  boundsx,
  boundsy,
  mouse = {
    down: false,
    button: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    px: 0,
    py: 0
  };

var Point = function(x, y) {

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.px = x;
  this.py = y;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.pin_x = null;
  this.pin_y = null;

  this.constraints = [];
};

Point.prototype.update = function(delta) {

  if (mouse.down) {

    var diff_x = this.x - mouse.x,
      diff_y = this.y - mouse.y,
      dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y);

    if (mouse.button == 1) {

      if (dist < mouse_influence) {
        this.px = this.x - (mouse.x - mouse.px) * 1.8;
        this.py = this.y - (mouse.y - mouse.py) * 1.8;
      }

    } else if (dist < mouse_cut) this.constraints = [];
  }

  this.add_force(0, gravity);

  delta *= delta;
  nx = this.x + ((this.x - this.px) * .99) + ((this.vx / 2) * delta);
  ny = this.y + ((this.y - this.py) * .99) + ((this.vy / 2) * delta);

  this.px = this.x;
  this.py = this.y;

  this.x = nx;
  this.y = ny;

  this.vy = this.vx = 0
};

Point.prototype.draw = function() {

  if (!this.constraints.length) return;

  var i = this.constraints.length;
  while (i--) this.constraints[i].draw();
};

Point.prototype.resolve_constraints = function() {

  if (this.pin_x != null && this.pin_y != null) {

    this.x = this.pin_x;
    this.y = this.pin_y;
    return;
  }

  var i = this.constraints.length;
  while (i--) this.constraints[i].resolve();

  this.x > boundsx ? this.x = 2 * boundsx - this.x : 1 > this.x && (this.x = 2 - this.x);
  this.y < 1 ? this.y = 2 - this.y : this.y > boundsy && (this.y = 2 * boundsy - this.y);
};

Point.prototype.attach = function(point) {

  this.constraints.push(
    new Constraint(this, point)
  );
};

Point.prototype.remove_constraint = function(constraint) {

  this.constraints.splice(this.constraints.indexOf(constraint), 1);
};

Point.prototype.add_force = function(x, y) {

  this.vx += x;
  this.vy += y;
};

Point.prototype.pin = function(pinx, piny) {
  this.pin_x = pinx;
  this.pin_y = piny;
};

var Constraint = function(p1, p2) {

  this.p1 = p1;
  this.p2 = p2;
  this.length = spacing;
};

Constraint.prototype.resolve = function() {

  var diff_x = this.p1.x - this.p2.x,
    diff_y = this.p1.y - this.p2.y,
    dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y),
    diff = (this.length - dist) / dist;

  if (dist > tear_distance) this.p1.remove_constraint(this);

  var px = diff_x * diff * 0.5;
  var py = diff_y * diff * 0.5;

  this.p1.x += px;
  this.p1.y += py;
  this.p2.x -= px;
  this.p2.y -= py;
};

Constraint.prototype.draw = function() {

  ctx.moveTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
};

var Cloth = function() {

  this.points = [];

  var start_x = canvas.width / 2 - cloth_width * spacing / 2;

  for (var y = 0; y <= cloth_height; y++) {

    for (var x = 0; x <= cloth_width; x++) {

      var p = new Point(start_x + x * spacing, start_y + y * spacing);

      x != 0 && p.attach(this.points[this.points.length - 1]);
      y == 0 && p.pin(p.x, p.y);
      y != 0 && p.attach(this.points[x + (y - 1) * (cloth_width + 1)])

      this.points.push(p);
    }
  }
};

Cloth.prototype.update = function() {

  var i = physics_accuracy;

  while (i--) {
    var p = this.points.length;
    while (p--) this.points[p].resolve_constraints();
  }

  i = this.points.length;
  while (i--) this.points[i].update(.016);
};

Cloth.prototype.draw = function() {

  ctx.beginPath();

  var i = cloth.points.length;
  while (i--) cloth.points[i].draw();

  ctx.stroke();
};

function update() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  cloth.update();
  cloth.draw();

  requestAnimFrame(update);
}

function start() {

  canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    mouse.button = e.which;
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      mouse.down = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
    mouse.down = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  boundsx = canvas.width - 1;
  boundsy = canvas.height - 1;

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';

  cloth = new Cloth();

  update();
}

window.onload = function() {

  canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = 560;
  canvas.height = 350;

  start();
};
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: good codepen :D playing with it spidey web LOL :P

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have copy and pasted the website exactly how it is, you're missing opening and closing style tags around the CSS, and script tags around the JS.

Comment: No, since I didn't have much time I just put all the code (not including font js), into one code thing. I have the HTML, CSS and JS on different files. If it helps I am using Dreamweaver for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but you need this tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> YOUR JAVASCRIPT HERE </script>
<style type="text/css"> YOUR CSS HERE </style>
```

```js
/*
Copyright (c) 2013 dissimulate at Codepen

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/

document.getElementById('close').onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
  return false;
};

// settings

var physics_accuracy = 3,
  mouse_influence = 20,
  mouse_cut = 5,
  gravity = 1200,
  cloth_height = 30,
  cloth_width = 50,
  start_y = 20,
  spacing = 7,
  tear_distance = 60;

window.requestAnimFrame =
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };

var canvas,
  ctx,
  cloth,
  boundsx,
  boundsy,
  mouse = {
    down: false,
    button: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    px: 0,
    py: 0
  };

var Point = function(x, y) {

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.px = x;
  this.py = y;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.pin_x = null;
  this.pin_y = null;

  this.constraints = [];
};

Point.prototype.update = function(delta) {

  if (mouse.down) {

    var diff_x = this.x - mouse.x,
      diff_y = this.y - mouse.y,
      dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y);

    if (mouse.button == 1) {

      if (dist < mouse_influence) {
        this.px = this.x - (mouse.x - mouse.px) * 1.8;
        this.py = this.y - (mouse.y - mouse.py) * 1.8;
      }

    } else if (dist < mouse_cut) this.constraints = [];
  }

  this.add_force(0, gravity);

  delta *= delta;
  nx = this.x + ((this.x - this.px) * .99) + ((this.vx / 2) * delta);
  ny = this.y + ((this.y - this.py) * .99) + ((this.vy / 2) * delta);

  this.px = this.x;
  this.py = this.y;

  this.x = nx;
  this.y = ny;

  this.vy = this.vx = 0
};

Point.prototype.draw = function() {

  if (!this.constraints.length) return;

  var i = this.constraints.length;
  while (i--) this.constraints[i].draw();
};

Point.prototype.resolve_constraints = function() {

  if (this.pin_x != null && this.pin_y != null) {

    this.x = this.pin_x;
    this.y = this.pin_y;
    return;
  }

  var i = this.constraints.length;
  while (i--) this.constraints[i].resolve();

  this.x > boundsx ? this.x = 2 * boundsx - this.x : 1 > this.x && (this.x = 2 - this.x);
  this.y < 1 ? this.y = 2 - this.y : this.y > boundsy && (this.y = 2 * boundsy - this.y);
};

Point.prototype.attach = function(point) {

  this.constraints.push(
    new Constraint(this, point)
  );
};

Point.prototype.remove_constraint = function(constraint) {

  this.constraints.splice(this.constraints.indexOf(constraint), 1);
};

Point.prototype.add_force = function(x, y) {

  this.vx += x;
  this.vy += y;
};

Point.prototype.pin = function(pinx, piny) {
  this.pin_x = pinx;
  this.pin_y = piny;
};

var Constraint = function(p1, p2) {

  this.p1 = p1;
  this.p2 = p2;
  this.length = spacing;
};

Constraint.prototype.resolve = function() {

  var diff_x = this.p1.x - this.p2.x,
    diff_y = this.p1.y - this.p2.y,
    dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y),
    diff = (this.length - dist) / dist;

  if (dist > tear_distance) this.p1.remove_constraint(this);

  var px = diff_x * diff * 0.5;
  var py = diff_y * diff * 0.5;

  this.p1.x += px;
  this.p1.y += py;
  this.p2.x -= px;
  this.p2.y -= py;
};

Constraint.prototype.draw = function() {

  ctx.moveTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
};

var Cloth = function() {

  this.points = [];

  var start_x = canvas.width / 2 - cloth_width * spacing / 2;

  for (var y = 0; y <= cloth_height; y++) {

    for (var x = 0; x <= cloth_width; x++) {

      var p = new Point(start_x + x * spacing, start_y + y * spacing);

      x != 0 && p.attach(this.points[this.points.length - 1]);
      y == 0 && p.pin(p.x, p.y);
      y != 0 && p.attach(this.points[x + (y - 1) * (cloth_width + 1)])

      this.points.push(p);
    }
  }
};

Cloth.prototype.update = function() {

  var i = physics_accuracy;

  while (i--) {
    var p = this.points.length;
    while (p--) this.points[p].resolve_constraints();
  }

  i = this.points.length;
  while (i--) this.points[i].update(.016);
};

Cloth.prototype.draw = function() {

  ctx.beginPath();

  var i = cloth.points.length;
  while (i--) cloth.points[i].draw();

  ctx.stroke();
};

function update() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  cloth.update();
  cloth.draw();

  requestAnimFrame(update);
}

function start() {

  canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    mouse.button = e.which;
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      mouse.down = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
    mouse.down = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  boundsx = canvas.width - 1;
  boundsy = canvas.height - 1;

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';

  cloth = new Cloth();

  update();
}

window.onload = function() {

  canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = 560;
  canvas.height = 350;

  start();
};
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: allerta;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #646464;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
}
.center {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 132px;
}
.button-wrap {
    margin-right: 25px;
    top: 133px;
    margin-top: -139px;
}
.rad-button {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: allerta;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s all ease;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #777;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #B8B8B8;
    font-style: normal;
}
.rad-button.good {
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
    color: #2F4F4F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #759f87;
}
.rad-button.good:hover {
  background-color: #caf3db;
  top: -2px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #759f87;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.rad-button.good:active {
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #759f87;
  background-color: #a5dabc;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}


.fade {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

ul, ol, dl {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #FAEBD7;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: allerta;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -26px;
}
h2{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #2F4F4F;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px;
    font-size: x-large;
}
h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #FAEBD7;
    font-family: allerta;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}

a:link {
    color: #FAEBD7;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: allerta;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
a:visited {
    color: #6E6C64;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CAF3DB;
    font-family: allerta;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
}

.sidebar1 {
    float: right;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 780px;
    display: inline;
    top: 10px;
}


.content ul, .content ol {
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
nav a, nav a:visited {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active, nav a:focus {
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    color: #FFF;
    min-width: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

/* ~~ The footer ~~ */
footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

header, section, footer, aside, article, figure {
    display: block;
    color: #FAEBD7;
    text-align: center;
    left: -14px;
    top: 134px;
}

#c {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ewan Lyon Home</title>
<link href="../CSS/HTML5_twoColFixRtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/allerta:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <article class="content">
    <h1>Ewan Lyon</h1>

        <div class = "center">
            <div class = "button-wrap">
                <button class = "rad-button good flat">Photoshop</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "button-wrap">
            <a href="Illustrator.html">
                <button class = "rad-button good flat">Illustrator</button>
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "center">
            <div class = "button-wrap">
                <button class = "rad-button good flat">About Me</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "button-wrap">
                <button class = "rad-button good flat">RICE</button>
            </div>
        </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/ClothSimulation.js"></script>

    <canvas id="c"></canvas>

    <div id="top">
        <a id="close"></a>
    </div>

  <footer>
    <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/4.0/80x15.png" /></a><br />Ewan Lyon
  </footer>
  </article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```